# Unable to launch netcoredbg with dev env

Tags: .net, neovim

I am using astrovim which utilizes nvim-dap but when i start the debugging the application is launched in Production mode despite my best effort to set it to dev mode.

setting env manually to dev in appsettings.development.json

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by creating a launch.json file and building the system using this file

```
dotnet build -c launch.json
```

in this file i created configurations object and specified the environment in that

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"configurations": [
{
  "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
  "type": "coreclr",
  "request": "launch",
  "preLaunchTask": "build",

  "launchBrowser": {
    "enabled": true,
  }

  "launchUrl": "swagger",
  "env": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
  }
 }
]
}
```